# Select one row for each main identifier where there are multiple rows for each id with null and non-null values

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a query with rows that return results as shown here:

```
+--------------+------+-------+-------+------+------+--------+--------+--------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
|ID            | LC1  | IL1   |  IL2  | WT1  |  WT2 |   HN1  |  HN2   |   St   | P/H  | PN1  |  PN2 |  C1  |  C2  |  PW  |
+--------------+------+-------+-------+------+------+--------+--------+--------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
|NDP-5-SC-0014 | NULL | NULL  | 24.52 | NULL | 12.7 |  NULL  | 521502 |  NULL  | NULL | NULL | 509  | FBE  | NULL | NULL |
|NDP-5-SC-0014 | NULL | 18.07 | 24.52 | 12.7 | 12.7 | 402772 | 521502 | 341615 | NULL | 380  | 509  | FBE  | FBE  | NULL |
|NDP-5-SC-0014 | NULL | 18.08 |  NULL | 12.7 | NULL | 402772 |  NULL  |  NULL  | NULL | 380  | NULL | NULL | FBE  | NULL |
```

and I want to select it so that it shows as:

```
+--------------+------+-------+-------+------+------+--------+--------+--------+------+------+------+------+------+------+    
|ID            | LC1  | IL1   |  IL2  | WT1  |  WT2 |   HN1  |  HN2   |   St   | P/H  | PN1  |  PN2 |  C1  |  C2  |  PW  |
+--------------+------+-------+-------+------+------+--------+--------+--------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
|NDP-5-SC-0014 | NULL | 18.07 | 24.52 | 12.7 | 12.7 | 402772 | 521502 | 341615 | NULL | 380  | 509  | FBE  | FBE  | NULL |
```

I want to select one row for each ID and grab just one of the non-null values for the rest of the fields.

Comment: In column `IL1`, you'll need to decide whether you want `18.07` or `18.08`. Actually this is true for the rest of the columns, you'll need to decide whether you want the latter record, earlier record OR the larger or lesser value (numeric or alphabetically larger or smaller).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conceptually.. You want to use an aggregate like `MAX()` or `MIN()` (whichever best fits your needs) on all of the columns except `ID`, which you will `GROUP BY`.

Without seeing your query it is impossible to give you the correct one back, but it will be something like:

```
SELECT ID, MAX(LC1), MAX(IL1), rest of columns
FROM (Your Query) A --May or may not need to put your query in a derived table
GROUP BY ID
```

Comment: I think you want `MIN` versus `MAX` here. Look at IL1

Comment: @scsimon Yeah OP said `grab just one of the non-null values` but you're right that if it matters then `MIN()` fits their expected output.

Comment: Didn't know about min max, just what I needed.